# Change function to read tab delimited file into datable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to change the below function to read from a tab delimited file any ideas how to do this?

```
Public Function ConvertCsvToDatatable(ByVal ColumnNames As Boolean) As DataTable
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        For Each columnName In getColumns(ColumnNames)
            dt.Columns.Add(columnName)
        Next
        Dim fileReader As New StreamReader(FileName)
        If ColumnNames Then
            fileReader.ReadLine()
        End If
        Dim line As String = fileReader.ReadLine
        While Not IsNothing(line)
            line = line.Replace(Chr(34), "")
            dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
            line = fileReader.ReadLine
        End While
        fileReader.Close()
        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log to file
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably replace the following line:

```
dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
```

With:

```
dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(vbTab))
```

That should split on tab delimited values...

That said, I would really recommend a specialized library to do this, since SCV / TSV can be fairly complicated.  I like [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The `TextFieldParser` class, which is built-in to the .NET framework, supports reading CSV and TSV.

Comment: I recall dimly that the KbCsv library was superior when dealing with complicated csv, which included commas in the columns...

Comment: I don't doubt it.  If nothing else, the public interface of the `TextFieldParser` is clunky, which makes it difficult to use.  I've never heard of KBCsv, but it's easy to imagine it being better than the MS one.  However, sometimes it's nice to use built-in classes, when they are available, just to avoid additional third-party dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Change `line.Split(",")` to `line.Split(vbTab)`. This will let you use the tab character as delimiter instead of a comma.

Comment: `\t` won't work in VB.NET.  Use `ControlChars.Tab` or `vbTab`.

Comment: Yep, just realised I was thinking in C#. Thanks for pointing that out.